# discord.js code not working on heroku hosting

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    const { get } = require('snekfetch')
    const Discord = require('discord.js')
    message.delete()
    try {
        get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then(res => {
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setImage(res.body.message)
            return message.channel.send({embed});
        });
    } catch(err) {
        return message.channel.send(err.stack);
    }
}
```

This is the command, on local hosting this command works, is it blocked by heroku or something ?

Comment: Well, what do the logs say? In what way does it not work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What does "not working" mean?

Comment: it is confusing bsc there are not any errors

Comment: @Chris sorry : ) - not working - if i write !dog it deletes my message but its not sending an image

Comment: and if i use same code but with !cat command (another api) it works, maybe this api is blocked on heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`snekfetch` has been deprecated. Instead use [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

---

Example:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
 .then((res) => res.text())
 .then((body) => {
  const embed = new MessageEmbed().setImage(body);
  message.channel.send(embed);
 });
```

Comment: @Liones100 can u give me ready code example bcs i dont understand this node :(

Comment: erorr : embed.image.url: Not a well formed URL. U should pay attention to this : .setImage(res.body.message) this is code for url for image can u edit this once again please :) ? Thanks <3

Comment: bcs i can't figure out how to do this

Comment: so can u help me this time too :D?